# Is the italic button broken?

Tags: support, formatting

Why is *this* italic but [my text in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-was-the-funniest-development-bug-youve-seen/2308#2308) is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mmyers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/233/mmyers) edited my answer and fixed it. Turns out the underscore in the Twitter name "Nick_Lalone" needed to be escaped with a backslash; then suddenly it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's because underscores are another way to form italics, so the parser got confused.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspected* because it's a *[hyperlink](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/about)*, but when I tried it, it worked fine. Make sure the asterisks are matching, either inside or outside the brackets.

[*Funniest-bug link*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-was-the-funniest-development-bug-youve-seen/2308#2308) - I created this link by

- typing the words "Funniest-bug link"
- selecting the entire line
- clicking the *link* button and filling the box with the URL.
- while the text was still selected, clicking the ***I*** button.

And it seems to work fine. Making this Answer a wiki so you can edit/see the raw text. (You might do the same so we can see your text).

I also noticed that I used asterisks *both* inside and outside my URL brackets, so apparently it doesn't matter where they appear.

Comment: Hmm. I just edited the answer so that my hyperlink is an actual link rather than just http... text, and it still shows the same problem. I think it's a real bug. And yes things match, I'm a programmer after all. :)